# Is there any way to create only api client codes in openapi.generator

Tags: openapi-generator

I want to use Open Api Generator to generate client codes of my api to be used in my KMP project.

I configured `build.gradle.kts` files according to provided guideline and it generates codes (in `build/generated` folder as specified in documentation). But not just the code but also module layout files such as `build.gradle.kts` and so on

[image: Screenshot of generated files by openapi-generator gradle plugin]

If you look at the bottom of picture, you can see a folder named `moko` which is generated sources from resources in compile time by moko library.

I want codes generated by openapi-generator, generaed like moko (and sqldelight) not to generate another module.

The problem is NOT just the layout, generated code is not detected by IDE and gradle so at the compile time, they make errors